# Calling secure WCF service manually

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I need to call a WCF manually (via HttpWebRequest). I can call my service by adding a web reference and calling it through the proxy, so I know the service is setup correctly and the certs, web config, etc. is all correct. Based on samples I've found, I think I'm doing it correctly, but still getting an internal error 500.

EDIT: WebService is using wsHttpBinding.

Console app code is:

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1");
    string strRequest = Properties.Resources.TextFile1;

    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");

    using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strRequest), 0, strRequest.Length);
    }

    using (WebResponse res = req.GetResponse())
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }
```

TextFile1 is the XML request... just hard coding for now:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:f3c2172e-eeb9-4dfd-8e1b-3a623088b78f</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <value>0</value>
      <value2>test</value2>
    </GetData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What am I missing here? There are no further details inside the exception.

EDIT:

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RequestUserName" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
      <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
              <binding name="RequestUserName">
                  <security mode="Message">
                      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                  </security>
              </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
            <serviceCredentials>
                <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfServiceLibrary1.DistributorValidator, WcfServiceLibrary1" />
                <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share your `web.config`.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta - Hi. Web.config has been added. Standard stuff. I did see the status code is "ProtocolError".

Comment: Are you able to hit the service using SoapUI?  If so, compare what that uses against the headers/methods you're using.

Comment: I dont thinl it is possible the way you are trying to achieve....you have to use ChannelFactory to call WCf service from client...but again why not use Proxy?

Comment: @Viru, I need to be able to call *any* web service dynamically on the fly (user specifies URL, namespace, parameters, etc). I am able to do this with HttpWebBinding (unsecure), but we want to add support for wsHttpBinding (secure).

Comment: @DanField, I did try use Fiddler and a service reference, but there was a whole bunch of gobbly gook being sent. From what I have seen this should be possible. I will try SoapUI and see what that sends.

Comment: Don't know why the down vote, but who would be crazy enough to consume  a `WsHttpBinding` over `Http`?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use [`HttpWebBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172(v=vs.110).aspx) to access any WCF service over `Http`.